# Mysql count cells containing comma separated values

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql statement that uses the group_concact() function to aggregate a number of values based on a common id as comma separated values. Here is some sample data:

```
name    value
sam     23
betty   22
sam     21,25
paul    19
ed      21,25,19
ed      19
```

What I want to do in the output is count the number of instances of each value and treat the comma separated values as as an instance of 'multi'.  I do not care about how many values are listed just that it is more than one.

```
name    19  21  22  23  25  multi
sam                 1       1
betty           1           
paul    1                   
ed      1                   1
```

In my SELECT portion I am using statements like:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN value = 23 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as '23',
```

How do I handle counting the 'multi' cells?

Comment: just select the count and when that is > 1 that means its a multi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to count multi rows (rows with value that contains 2 or more numbers) just look for any comma in the value

```
SUM(CASE WHEN value LIKE '%,%' THEN 1 ELSE null END) as multi
```